# Spark datagrid columns issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a spark Datagrid with lot of columns. The problem is that if i have a long text in a cell, then the text goes over other columns.

Any ideas how to fix this? I want the text to stay in it cell, if it longer than the columns width, then the text to be truncated somehow.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try making a custom item renderer for the columns that are spilling over, and add a tooltip to when you hover the mouse, you can see the entire cell contents:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="dataFieldName">
  <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
   <s:GridItemRenderer >
    <s:Label toolTip="{data.dataFieldName}"  text="{data.dataFieldName}"/>
   </s:GridItemRenderer>
   </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```